# Is Dbset/Dbcontext list loaded before linq or after linq

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

In mvc when you use Dbset/Dbcontext using sql at what point does the Table gets queried? And at what point is the table loaded in the List that Linq statements are querying?

Lets say I have a model like

```
public class MRN : DbContext
{
    public MRN()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<message> MRNS { get; set; }
}
[Table("MRN")]
public class message
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
 }
```

My controller is like

```
public class MRNController : Controller
    {
    private MRN mrn = new MRN(); // Is the linq list loaded here?
    public ActionResult Someaction(){........
    ......}
```

An action

```
public ActionResult somelinq(int id)
{ 
var k = mrn.MRNS.Find(id); //Is the private variable **mrn** already loaded here or does it loads during the linq statement or does linq queries actual table itself?
 }
```

Can someone elaborate on the loading with regards to the SQL table i.e at what steps are the actual sql queries performed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query will be executed as soon as you materialize an `IQueryable`. For example when calling `.First/Single(OrDefault)`, `.ToList()` or `foreach` on it.

Comment: so when you declare the private variable it is empty?

Comment: Well that's a whole different question, but if you mean whether a `DbContext` accesses the database as soon as you initialize it: no. In the code you showed, only at `.Find()` the database will be hit.

Comment: To be more explicit, the expression is parsed requested from the database when you call .GetEnumerator (or it is called for you by foreach, databinding, etc). The exception here is types that don't return enumerables (First, Single, aggregates without grouping, etc)